# Change activity gui from service

Tags: android

I have an android chat app, and in the one fragment called taskfragment there is a list of your chats with a notification counter.

I have a class called chatService that deals with notifications, whenever a notification comes through the chatservice updates the db to increment the notification number on the particular task.

When taskfragment opens it calls a function called refreshTasks(), which updates the gui from the db.

My problem is, if the user is in taskfragment and they get a notification, I need to call refreshtasks from the chatservice, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager` for your purpose.
The idea is to send broadcast from service when new message is received and receive it on your fragment

```
class YourService extends GcmListenerService{
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    Intent pushNotification = new Intent("pushNotification");
    //put any extra data using Intent.putExtra() method         
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
    ...
    }
}
```

Now receive it on your fragment:

```
class TaskFragment extends Fragment{
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("pushNotification")) {
                // new push message is received
                //update UI
                handlePushNotification(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // registering the receiver for new notification
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("pushNotification"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //unregister receiver here
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

You can refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277) or find tutorial about it on web.

Comment: not a biggie but the (this) needs to change to getActivity()